# ScadaLts : Where to get the sample data sql scripts

Tags: sample-data, scadalts

After execute "createTables-mysql.sql",and insert 
data into tables 'systemsettings' and 'users':

```
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (1,'admin','0DPiKuNIrrVmD8IUCuw1hQxNqZc=','admin@yourMangoDomain.com','','Y','N',1275399205446,1,NULL,0,'N');
INSERT INTO `systemSettings` VALUES ('databaseSchemaVersion','1.12.4');
```

Finally,I success to run the scada-lts.
but where can i find some sample data of scadalts?

Comment: Please ask specific question about your programming issue.

Comment: So far I have written some tutorials for scada-lts (for which no sample data was needed), but it's a good idea to add sample data for more complex ones.